# If I create a delegating handler in web api to do some pre processing logic. will it hamper the performance?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have created a delegating handler to handle my pre processing logic. The logic simply checks for any special character that we have in the request and then encode it and moves on in the life cycle. Below is the code:

```
public class EncodingRequest : DelegatingHandler
{
protected override async Task<System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //deserialize the request that is in json format
        dynamic dynamicJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

        //using regex to match the pattern for the Json request object and directly replacing and encoding the desired value

        //SUGGESTION: Used JSon JProperties to modified the request by encoding it. This was taking more loop as we need to go through every child element of Json
        //If the JSON have child hierarchy(a child having its own child and so on) then we have to loop to each child to encode the request. So, more convenient way was
        //to use regex Replace method that matches the pattern and replace it with the new value.

        string regexPattern = "(?<=: \")[^\",\r\n]*";
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex rgx = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(regexPattern);

        //using REGEX's replace function to find the matching pattern and then replace the value with the encoded value
        dynamicJson = rgx.Replace(dynamicJson.ToString(), new MatchEvaluator((m) => { return Encoder.HtmlEncode(m.ToString()); }));

        //chanding the request content with the modified request with header type as "application/json"
        request.Content = new StringContent(dynamicJson,
                                System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
                                "application/json");//CONTENT-TYPE header

        Core.Logging.LogManager.LogVerbose(request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

        //original call
        HttpResponseMessage response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        Core.Logging.LogManager.LogVerbose(response.ToString());


        return response;
    }
}
```

So, this is working as expected. However, will this hamper the performance of my web api. If yes, how will it hamper and what other technique should I use. If it is WCF, then I would have made use of the runtime architecture(IServiceBehavior, IOperationBehavior). How will I proceed apart from using Delegating Handler if it hamper the performance.

Comment: Every piece of code you run in the pipeline will cost you some. To real question is, does it matter? I do not know what is acceptable nor how much extra resources it costs now.

Comment: Anyway, I do know that I would change `request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result` to `await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`

Comment: 1 micro-optimization: create one static copy of `rgx` to avoid insta-garbage on every call to this handler.  On a busy system these 1-time use strings will eventually cause the garbage collection process to run.

2 Optimization: You are calling ReadAsStringAsync() twice.

3 Question: Is the LogVerbose(response) call doing what you want/need it to do?  Logging large responses can be expensive depending on your logger.

Comment: thank you for your response @NoRefundsNoReturns. My respose is not large, it simply contains request of 7-8 parameters.

Comment: @PeterBons Thank you for your response. I was using await at the end when I am passing my updated request to the action method

Comment: @Yash - you asked about performance.  Those things will impact performance.  10 requests per day?  Who cares.  20K RPS (like my service) I care.